# Uncaught ReferenceError for constant defined in same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [`remark-math`](https://github.com/Rokt33r/remark-math/) to render maths equations from Markdown. This has previously been working without a hitch, however after I refactored some seemingly unrelated code, I now get the following exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: INLINE_MATH_DOUBLE is not defined
    at Of.inlineTokenizer (inline.js:12)
    at Of.tokenize [as tokenizeInline] (tokenizer.js:111)
    at Of.atxHeading (heading-atx.js:148)
    at Of.tokenize [as tokenizeBlock] (tokenizer.js:111)
    at Of.parse (parse.js:41)
    at Function.parse (index.js:275)
    at pipelineParse (index.js:22)
    at wrapped (index.js:93)
    at next (index.js:56)
    at Object.run (index.js:30)
```

The relevant code from `./node_modules/remark-math/inline.js` looks like the following:

```
const ESCAPED_INLINE_MATH = /^\\\$/
const INLINE_MATH = /^\$((?:\\\$|[^$])+)\$/
const INLINE_MATH_DOUBLE = /^\$\$((?:\\\$|[^$])+)\$\$/  // << defined here?

module.exports = function inlinePlugin (opts) {
  function inlineTokenizer (eat, value, silent) {
    let isDouble = true
    let match = INLINE_MATH_DOUBLE.exec(value) // << line 12, error here
    // ...remaining code
```

The constant appears to be defined in scope!

I'm building using webpack and the [`chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate`](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) template. Any hints as to why this kind of exception would suddenly be happening? (I've tried a complete reinstall of `node_modules`.)

Comment: Please show us the change in the "seemingly unrelated" part that causes this to work or not.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, there are hundreds of changes across about 30 odd files as it was a major refactor. Obviously I can't post all that, however on comparing branches there were no changes that impacted the node_modules and none were related to code that called them. The problem persisted when I checked out earlier tagged versions, and as per my answer below this appears to be an issue with npm install. Running yarn instead fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe some issues happen from **webpack** building.

if the error still happen, and you want to avoid it, you can use this

```
GLOBAL.INLINE_MATH_DOUBLE = /^\$\$((?:\\\$|[^$])+)\$\$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this didn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the dependencies with `yarn` instead of `npm` and the issue went away.